# How to trace a html button non-event? (Rails Authorization With Pundit)

Tags: html, events, button, wireshark

### Day 1:

I am following along closely on https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qruGD_8ry7k.  I'm at 1:02:11 in the video.

[image]

When I click on a "Change Role" button, sometimes I make it through to the controller (def update) action and sometimes I don't.  If I don't then re-clicking the button does not seem to help.  Refreshing the page is almost guaranteed to make the button work.

Using Firefox's debugger,
[image]
how can I tell that Firefox has triggered a button event?

The html for each user row (a partial named _user.html.erb) is

```
<td>
  <%= link_to user.email, user %>
</td>
<td>
  <%= form_for(user) do |f| %>
    <%= f.select(:role, User.roles.keys.map {|role| [role.titleize,role]}) %>
    <td>
    <button><%= f.submit 'Change Role' %></button>
    </td>
  <% end %>
</td>
<td>
  <%= link_to("Delete user", user_path(user), :data => { :confirm => "Are you sure?" }, :method => :delete, :class => 'button') unless user == current_user %>
</td>
```

---

### Day 2:

I read a wonderful article:
http://andrewberls.com/blog/post/rails-from-request-to-response-part-1--introduction

So I placed a breakpoint at /home/real-estate-data-mining/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-4.2.8/lib/rails/application.rb:163

So I Installed WireShark. To see if a POST is going out when I press the Change Role button.  It isn't.

Anyone know what would cause the submit not to send a POST?

Answer (score 0):

Disable Turbolinks in Gemfile.

See https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/rubyonrails-talk/_Cc_foZ78oI